# Show/Hide div container based on id value on list & div container

Tags: jquery

Simple logic need to be fixed.

If li has class name "selected" on id.. get that value and match with div container. If li & div id are same display that div container and hide other id containers.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="slist selected" id="ele1"><a href="javascript:;">Element 1</a></li>
  <li class="slist" id="ele2"><a href="javascript:;">Element 2</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="cwrapper">
  <div class="contentEle">
    <div class="content ele1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
    </div>
    <div class="content ele2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.slist').each(function () {
if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    var $filterEle = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(600);
    $('.cwrapper .contentEle > div.content').not($filterEle).hide();
}
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem may be that `this.id` is not always returns right value especially with jQuery functions, I suggest to use `$(this).attr('id')` instead.

```
$('.slist').each(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
       $('.cwrapper .contentEle > div.content').hide();
       $('.' + $(this).attr('id')).fadeIn(600);
    }
    });
```

Comment: `this.id` is returning just fine.

Comment: var $sListEle = $('.sist').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $ele = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(600);
    $('.cwrapper .contentEle > div.content').not($ele).hide();
    $sListEle.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

Comment: On click function works fine.. Only on load its not filtering out

Comment: This solution hides all `.content` elements for each `.selected` element. Your `hide()` function should be outside your `each`

Answer (score 0):

I would use HTML `data-*` attributes, they're widely supported and offer a lot of flexibility.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="slist selected" id="ele1" data-div-link="ele1div"><a href="javascript:;">Element 1</a></li>
    <li class="slist" id="ele2" data-div-link="ele2div"><a href="javascript:;">Element 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="cwrapper">
    <div class="contentEle">
        <div class="content ele1div">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
        </div>
        <div class="content ele2div">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.cwrapper').find('div.content').hide();
$('.slist').each(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    if($li.hasClass('selected')) {
        $('.' + $li.data('div-link')).fadeIn(600);
    }
});
```

Documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly modified your javascript.
I would hide all the `.content` elements to begin with.

Then you can just use your `.selected` class as a selector and run through that/those element(s) and show the associated `div`.

Try **the snippet**, I think it does what you're trying to accomplish.

```js
$(".content").hide();
$('.slist.selected').each(function() {
  var $filterEle = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="slist" id="ele1"><a href="javascript:;">Element 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="slist selected" id="ele2"><a href="javascript:;">Element 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div class="cwrapper">
  <div class="contentEle">
    <div class="content ele1">
      [ele1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
    </div>
    <div class="content ele2">
      [ele2] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Additional Note:

There's nothing wrong with what you're doing but I agree with @RuubW (below), you should rather use data attributes for this. See this snippet (**which works with both click and onload**):

```js
$(".content").hide();
$('.slist.selected').each(function() {
  $('.' + $(this).data("divId")).fadeIn(1000);
});
$('.slist').click(function() {
  var $that = this;
  $('.' + $('.slist.selected').data('divId')).fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('.slist.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $($that).addClass('selected')
    $('.' + $('.slist.selected').data('divId')).fadeIn(500)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="slist selected" data-div-id="ele1"><a href="javascript:;">Element 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="slist" data-div-id="ele2"><a href="javascript:;">Element 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div class="cwrapper">
  <div class="contentEle">
    <div class="content ele1">
      [ele1] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
    </div>
    <div class="content ele2">
      [ele2] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi.. here we are generating ID value dynamically. Below code works fine on click function. need to figure out for onload function only.   var $sListEle = $('.sist').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $ele = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(600);
    $('.cwrapper .contentEle > div.content').not($ele).hide();
    $sListEle.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

Comment: @venkatesha have a look at the second snippet and you will see it working on click and on load.